# Label.Text doesn't change in a loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to change a text that a label displays during each iteration of a Do While loop in Visual Basic. One label (which displays an integer) works fine, however the other stays blank until the loop finishes and displays the final result. What could be the problem?

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles btnOblicz.Click
Dim W As Single
Dim L As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim Y As Double

W = Val(txtW.Text)

L = InputBox("Input L")

J = 0

If W > 0 And W < 100 Then

Do

    Y = (2 * Math.Sqrt(W)) / (L - J)
    J = J + 1
    lblJ.Text = Str(J)
    lblY.Text = Str(Y)
    MsgBox("Next...")

Loop Until Y < 0

Else
    MsgBox("No calculations, because the number is less than zero or greater than a hundred.")

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application.DoEvents(), as suggested by others, can work. However, you should be aware that it has some negative side-effects, such as the potential to create StackOverflowExceptions.

The *right* way to solve this problem is to use a [BackgroundWorker component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

As to *why* this happens... remember that all windows programs work by having, at their core, a loop which checks for messages from the user and operating system (things like mousemove events, clicks, keystrokes, etc). When you set the text property of a label, you are *not* telling the label to re-draw itself on the screen. Instead, you are posting an event to the operating system that your program's message loop must then receive and process. As new events come in, the message loop (or pump) sends those events to the proper method.

Your `btnCalc_Click()` function is one such method. If your function is running, it was called by the core windows messaging loop, which is now *waiting* for your method to complete and return control: it's blocked. The loop cannot continue receiving and dispatching methods until your function completes, and therefore nothing in your program's interface can be updated.

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me in small copy I did using VS2010

It may be that a message pump is required. Try this :

System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your window function which processes OS event message is inaccesible while your loop executes. Try explicitly call dispatching messages. E.g. insert after assigning labels text inside your loop

```
Application.DoEvents
```

Comment: Ha  just saw this, I was typing my answer before I saw your answer, we think alike Sir